# Why does my music overlap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason, my music overlaps on Minecraft. Any idea why? I would love to get this problem fixed! For example, when I play a music disc, background music overlaps it, and when I take out the disc, there would be a 75% chance that another background track would play. Any idea why? I'm on Minecraft 1.11

Comment: Have you tried to restart minecraft?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. Seen this issue on Mojang bug tracker too.

Comment: You could work with the sound settings. Turn background music off and keep everything else on.

Comment: tried that. still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a long-standing bug in many versions of the PC (Java-based) version of the program (and perhaps others). Here is one example of a bug reported for overlapping music: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-35856

It does not appear to be anything you are doing incorrectly. The only "fix" I have found is to shut down the program and restart it. Personally, I have encountered this bug often when switching between creative and survival.